# How to do "synchronized-with-resource" where obtaining the lock object must also be synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, synchronized

I have a `Map<String, Mutex> m` that I would like to lock on the Mutex, while also ensuring that the act of obtaining the lock is thread-safe:

```
//Assuming till here m.get(key) return a non-null value
synchronized (Mutex mtx = m.get(key)) {
  mtx.count++;
  //...
}
```

The following is not guaranteed in Java

```
Mutex mtx = m.get(key);
synchroinzed (mtx) {
  //thread 2 may acquire lock before thread 1 even thread 1 execute first
}
```

and neither is

```
synchronized (m.get(key)) {
  Mutex mtx = m.get(key); 
  //mtx could be null if other threads remove the key between 2 statements
  //because lock is only acquired on m.get(key), not m itself
}
```

How can I safely achieve this?

---

Edit:

My exact code right now:

```
public static <T, V> void lock (Map<T, Mutex<V>> mm, T uniqueKeyValue1, long waitMs) throws Mutex.WaitTimeoutException, InterruptedException {

    synchronized ( MapUtils.putIfAbsentRetNewVal(mm, uniqueKeyValue1, new Mutex<V>()) ) {

        Mutex<V> m = mm.get(uniqueKeyValue1);

        if (m.getLockCount() == 0) {
            m.incrementLockCount();
        }
        else {
            m.incrementLockCount();

            m.wait(waitMs);

            if (m.getValue() == null) {
                throw new Mutex.WaitTimeoutException();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @user2864740 I know it is not valid, otherwise I won't ask it here. Please take a look at my comment in the second example and see if it is valid

Comment: It would be easier for you to not remove the locks from the map and make them all long-lived.

Comment: @mvd The Map is a static field that is shared between threads, and it will grow indefinitely during the app's life if I do not remove them...

Comment: Why don't you just synchronize access on `m` itself? If the key can be removed and you want to avoid race conditions, that seems like the safest thing to do.

Comment: @sh0rug0ru Because other threads may acquire lock on the `m` (e.g. remove key)

Comment: That's good right? If the thread (A) that does `m.get(key)` acquires the lock on `m` first, and the thread (B) that does `m.remove(key)` acquires the lock on `m` second, then `m.get(key)` is guaranteed not to return a stale value because `m.remove(key)` cannot proceed until thread A releases the lock.

Comment: @sh0rug0ru Actually if other remove it first, I would like to allow it and make the synchronized to fail... with NullPointerException, which will be checked.

Comment: What is the real problem that you're trying to solve? What you've shown is a desired implementation, which may or may not match the problem. Your comment on option 2, in particular, shows a possible misunderstanding of how threads work.

Comment: @kdgregory The problem is I have a Map<String,Mutex> that indicates one of my threads is working on the key (so other threads would not write or read the same record with this key), but once one thread write to it, it can release it and all other threads can read and release it (and remove) as well.

Comment: You would like thread A to throw a `NullPointerException` if thread B acquires the lock first? Do an existence check for `key` when thread A acquires the lock, throw `NullPointerException` if `key` is non-existent in `m` after thread B releases the lock. Although, this isn't really a good use case for `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @sh0rug0ru It needs to be catched because if other threads remove it first, it will have to be `re-created` and `re-put` in the Map before I should acquire the lock on the mutex. There is no guarrentee the same key would not be used, but I cannot keep the key in the memory forever

Comment: Don't use exceptions for this. It is not an exceptional situation that other threads can remove the mutex from `m`, it looks like that is by design. So, after thread A acquires the lock and finds the mutex identified by `key` is removed, must all threads looking for the mutex identified by `key` wait until the mutex is recreated? Why not create it right then, when the existence check fails? Guard the check and create in the same synchronized block. Also, if you don't want all threads (even those looking for other values of `key`) to block, you need a striped lock. Check out ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: That's a better problem statement, because it describes what you're actually trying to achieve. I recommend that you edit your question, starting from that point, and adding in the conditions under which threads can acquire or release the mutex, or remove the key from the map.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-problem, and it doesn't have anything to do with with-resources. Use option 2. What you're asking for won't solve that problem. What you would need is not a with-resources but something that would synchronize on the map, then synchronize on the mutex, then release the synchronization on the map. You can't accompish that with synchronization because of the static scoping.

What you need is in fact another Mutex. Or, just accept the race. It's benign. You don't care which thread executes first.

Comment: I didn't say anything about try-with-resource? Another mutex is an option, but accepting the race is not...

Comment: Accepting the race is not why not?

Answer (score 0):

The language need not have a "synchronize with resources" construct because the JVM guarantees that it will release the lock when the synchronized block exits.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you have to lock on the map so no other thread can modify it while the current thread is using it ( `m.get(key)` ), perform your operation and then release the lock.

```
Map<String, Mutex> m = ...
synchronized( m ) { // only a single thread can access m now 
   Mutex mtx = m.get(key);
   mtx.count++;
} // releases the lock
```

Comment: This has the negative aspect that the lock is now 'global', independent of the actual mutex objects.. Probably defeats the purpose, although the overall task is vague to me.